# Select MaxDate where hh:mm:ss makes the difference

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to select the maximum date from a table where hh:mm:ss is selected?

My query is the following, and returns the latest date, but if there are different times recorded, the date will be returned twice. What I want is to get the absolute maxDate.

```
   SELECT * FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[DogTags] t1
     JOIN
    OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'SELECT [TimeStamp]
    ,[Name]
    ,[Owner]
    ,[Address]
     FROM PETS
 WHERE TimeStamp IN (SELECT MAX(TimeStamp) FROM [LinkedServer].[PETS]
    GROUP BY [Name])')t2
    ON t1.TAGS collate DATABASE_DEFAULT = t2.Name collate DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

This query returns the following table:

```
TAGS|TimeStamp              | Name  |Owner | Address    |
ROLF|2010-03-03 16:59:01.190| ROLF  |OLSEN | Juniper St.|
ROLF|2010-03-03 19:40:01.182| ROLF  |OLSEN | Juniper St.|
BLAD|2012-05-01 14:35:11.182| BLAD  |JOHN  | Maple St.  |
```

The records I want is:

```
TAGS|TimeStamp              | Name  |Owner | Address    |
ROLF|2010-03-03 19:40:01.182| ROLF  |OLSEN | Juniper St.|
BLAD|2012-05-01 14:35:11.182| BLAD  |JOHN  | Maple St.  |
```

Does anyone knows the solution how to filter the records to max time?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there a typo? How can tags and name be different in the results if the query says t1.TAGS = t2.Name?

Comment: Table DogTags has a single column named TAGS

Comment: But 'ROLF' != 'REX'. I'm a little confused.

Comment: OH yes you are right... I will Edit it. Thanks. Typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT * FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[DogTags] t1
    LEFT JOIN
    OPENQUERY(ROPSA, 'SELECT *
     FROM [CustomerDB].[PETS] t3
     INNER JOIN 
     (
     SELECT [Name] AS JailTag, MAX(TimeStamp) AS MaxDate
     FROM [ROPSA].[CustomerDB].[PETS]
     GROUP BY [Name]
     )t4
     ON t3.[Name] = t4.[JailTag] AND t3.TimeStamp = t4.MaxDate ')t2
    ON t1.TAGS collate DATABASE_DEFAULT = t2.Name collate DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Comment: Ah, so I think I just needed to use `[CustomerDB]` every time I referenced a table in `OPENQUERY`. I edited my answer.

Comment: if there is 2 rows with the same timestamp and tag, there still can be duplicates.

Comment: yes, you are right, in the case of having 2 rows with same values that can occur, but I can use SELECT DISTINCT and will sort it out.

Answer (score 3):

In the `OPENQUERY`, you could get the max timestamp for all the dogs at once, and then join to the original `PETS` table to get the other columns, like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[DogTags] t1
JOIN OPENQUERY(ROPSA,
    'SELECT [TimeStamp], [Name], [Owner], [Address]
     FROM [CustomerDB].[PETS] t3
     JOIN (SELECT [Name], MAX(TimeStamp) AS TimeStamp
           FROM [CustomerDB].[PETS]
           GROUP BY [Name]) t4
     ON t3.[Name]=t4.[Name] AND t3.TimeStamp=t4.TimeStamp') t2
ON t1.TAGS collate DATABASE_DEFAULT = t2.Name collate DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

EDIT: Needed to add `AS TimeStamp` in the subquery.

EDIT: Needed to specify the database everytime in `OPENQUERY`.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't works, I get the following error 
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "LinkedServer" returned message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.".

Comment: I will give it a try the other way around, I will first select the data from the linked server and then the local one. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I looked up that error, and it could be that I need to explicitly use the DB name in the `OPENQUERY`. I might need to use `[LinkedServer].[dbo].[PETS]`. Is the DB on the other server actually called LinkedServer?

Comment: no it is called ROPSA

Comment: Probably need to use [ROPSA].[PETS] instead of [LinkedServer].[PETS] then.

Comment: and basically the link looks like this [ROPSA].[CustomerDB].[PETS]

Comment: When you substitute [CustomerDB].[PETS] in there, does it work?

Comment: No, it still gives the same error

Comment: Your answer was almost correct, with some modifications it works. I will post the query I used to get the data I wanted

Answer (score 1):

Can try do like this (to get only one row per [Name] with maximum [TimeStamp] value):

```
Select PETS.* 
From PETS
    Inner Join
        (
            Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [TimeStamp] DESC, MyID Desc) Rn, MyID
            From PETS
        ) ps on PETS.MyID = ps.MyID and ps.Rn = 1
```